# How can I change howitzer/mortar range?

Tags: toy-soldiers

I have been playing a few levels in Toy Soldiers (Windows/Steam) and, when I take direct control of a howitzer or mortar position, I can rotate them and fire them but I cannot change range/elevation, and I am stuck with a random one (I guess the last one the position used when firing autonomously).

I have tried any key/mouse button I can think of, but so far none are working.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Nope, thought of searching for the developer support but got distracted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing's changed since this was posted, you just move your mouse forward/backward. It's hard to figure out since it's a very gradual change and seems to have some acceleration.

This is much more intuitive in the console version, where you just use the stick. I'm guessing they ported stick movements over to mouse movements without really putting much effort in, since that also makes flying planes pretty inconvenient in the Steam version.